# pandas dataframe text split

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data.frame as follows

```
ID.   Text
1.    Fruits grow on trees. Orange is a Citrus fruit.
2.    Root vegetables are in ground. Carrot is a root vegetable.
3.    Spinach is a leafy green. Kale is also a leafy green
```

I am trying to organize column `Text` as follows

```
Text=['Fruits grow on trees.','Orange is a Citrus fruit.','Root vegetables are in ground.','Carrot is a root vegetable.','Spinach is a leafy green.','Kale is also a leafy green.']
```

I tried `data["Text"].str.lower().to_numpy()` but this does not take care of splitting the data into two sentences...
thoughts on how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need do `split`

```
df.Text.str.split('. ').sum()
```

Comment: perfect this worked well (just had to remove the space after the . ````split('.')```` for my case. On another note, is there a way I can also convert it all to lower case in one go? Or would it need to be two statements? Thanks again!

Comment: @FlyingPickle df.Text.str.upper().str.split('. ').sum()